Image in UV Editing workspace lookings faded in the viewport
I added an image to my object in the UV Editing workspace, unwrapped it, and rotated it to be right side and in the middle, but on the other side of the head, the image is almost faded and not vibrant? I'm new here and don't know what it's about.


By default, the UV Editing workspace's viewport isn't set to be able to show textures on the mesh, so you had to make changes to that in order to be able to see that texture. (By the way, if you want to work on your textures or shaders, the Texture Paint or Shading workspaces are more appropriate than the UV Editing workspace.)
There aren't many ways for a texture to be shown "shadeless" in the viewport. I can think of only two out of my head:

Use a shadeless material (which you didn't as we can see the principled shader in your material settings and the image plugged in its base color input)
Set the viewport to Solid view with flat lighting and texture color:


If you didn't do any of these, then your mesh and their textures will always be shown with some form of shading and/or shadows from the viewport render settings if in Solid or Material views, or from the scene's lights and surrounding objects if in Render preview.
